# EOSJS how to query the top voters

Tags: eosjs

I can get some unsorted voters by using

```
await eos.getTableRows({
    json: true,
    code: 'eosio',
    scope: 'eosio',
    table: 'voters',
    // tableKey,
    // lowerBound,
    // upperBound,
    // limit,
    keyType: 'i64',
    indexPositio: '1'
  })
```

However, I wonder how to query for all the voters that are sorted based on how many votes were casted. Or even better, how to check the vote distribution of a specific block producer, similiar to what EOS Titan team is achieved here https://voters.eostitan.com/voters/50/0/21

Answer (score 0):

From the code in `eosio.system.hpp`, there is no index except PK on voters.
This means your tasks are not viable with eosjs it self.

I would suggest:

1. Ask eostitan if you could use their API:

   `https://explorer.eostitan.com/api/voters/${PAGE}`

   e.g. https://explorer.eostitan.com/api/voters/1
2. Find other APIs on the web.
3. Setup your own full node with mongo_plugin. **This would be a far complex process**.

   What you will need to do is:

   1. Setup a `mongo` server.
   2. Setup a `nodeos` server.
   3. Configure the `nodeos` server to use `mongo_plugin`.
   4. You may want to add filter to save only all **vote related** `action_traces` into mongo. This would save you a lot of space on `mongo` server. If you would like keep all `action_traces`, in our experience, the `mongo` server should have **at least 2TB storage**.
   5. Start `nodeos` server and wait for sync.
   6. With all the `action_traces` in your `mongo` server, you will need to add indices that makes your aggregation queries easier.
   7. Do the aggregation queries on your `mongo` server.